# Loud engine high rpms when accelerating?

Tags: engine, idle

I have a 2012 Ford Escape XLT, i cant take it on highway or go over 40mph because it hardly can get up to speed and my car shakes like crazy on highway and when i slow down from getting off the highway my tires feel “rough”. The engine is loud and sounds like its working excessively hard just to get up to 35mph. The O2 sensor is out so my car says rpms are 4-5k but really its more like 3k when its resisting so hard. the idle is horrible and shakes so hard i can hardly see from my rearview mirror. i have brought my car to countless mechanics and they can’t find a single thing wrong. they said it wasn’t the idle and that is was a suspension or something but it never fixed the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The O2 sensor being out will have zero effect on how fast the tachometer is saying your engine is revving to. If it says you're engine is 4-5k, then it's going 4-5k. And at that speed, yes, the engine can get quite loud. If it's going that fast and you are going anywhere, I'd suggest you might have an issue with the transmission, but your description is rather vague so I wouldn't know for sure. The best thing you can do is fix the issues you KNOW are wrong (ie: O2 sensor) and go from there.

Comment: Is the check engine light on. Along with suspecting transmission, a severe misfire can cause some of these symptoms. If the check engine light is not on then I'd be looking at the transmission as Paulster2 states. Another possibility might be brakes malfunctioning. If one or more wheels are very hot just after a drive the problem is probably in the brake system.